# getting selectedIndex for SkinnableDataContainer / List

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe

Is there something like `selectedIndex` for `SkinnableDataContainer`? It doesn't seem to be one of the available properties.

Answer (score 0):

Nick

Look at the following link to Adobe's site...  this will describe how to add the functionality to the SkinnableDataContainer class by extending it.

[SkinnableDataContainer Link](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Spark+SkinnableDataContainer)

Z

Answer (score 0):

I needed just this, a few days ago and found some components that should work. If you look at [spark.components.List](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html) which is a subclass of [spark.components.SkinnableDataContainer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/SkinnableDataContainer.html) you will see the selectedIndex property aswell as the selectedIndices property (for selecting multipleItems). If you dont need all of the List functionality [spark.components.supportClasses.ListBase](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ListBase.html) can be used.